# ODBC Tracing hides password

Tags: database, ms-access, odbc

I have a legacy Visual Basic application that uses an encrypted accdb database that I would like to backup. Sadly, the database is encrypted with a hard to decipher password (I tried basic stuff like B64, ASCII-Hex, etc). When trying to get the password with ODBC tracing, the trace contains ****** instead of the password. Is there an option I am missing to log password, since the app is using the system Access ODBC driver?

```
" -i            5f88-84bc   EXIT  SQLConnectW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HDBC                0x039E0DF0
    WCHAR *             0x039B2028 [      -3] "N_PERSONAL\ 0"
    SWORD                       -3 
    WCHAR *             0x79EF2430 [      -3] "******\ 0"
    SWORD                       -3 
    WCHAR *             0x79EF2430 [      -3] "******\ 0"
    SWORD                       -3
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because wants help cracking password.

Comment: Obviously, you can't simply pull the password by ODBC tracing, that would be a major breach in security for every application that uses ODBC.

Comment: @ErikA as per https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/168/Q168879/ it seems like it was possible before and they changed it to ODBC SPY which I can't find anywhere. Another thing I could do is write my own tracing dll, since apparently the who thing is done in pdbctrac.dll.

Comment: That refers to Windows 95, quite some time ago when insecure applications were the norm, and you can't go back that far with .accdb files. Obviously, you can extract the password, but I'd go for decompiling the application and analyzing that before I'd go the _custom ODBC tracer_ or _custom ODBC driver with identical name_ path (I guess a custom driver is easier than a custom tracer, since it doesn't need to do much, just log the password, and removing the password might have happened upstream from the tracer).